# Why is my loop slower when I remove code

Tags: c, gcc

When I remove the tests to compute minimum and maximum from the loop, the execution time is actually longer than with the test. How is that possible ?

Edit :
After running more test, it seems the runtime is not constant, ie the same code
can run in 9 sec or 13 sec.... So it was just a repetable coincidence. Repetable until you do enough tests that is...

Some details :

- execution time with the min max test : 9 sec
- execution time without the min max test : 13 sec
- `CFLAGS=-Wall -O2 -fPIC -g`
- gcc 4.4.3 32 bit
  Section to remove is now indicated in code

Some guess :
bad cache interaction ?

```
void    FillFullValues(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    double  X,Y,Z;
    double  p,q,r,p1,q1,r1;
    double  Ls,as,bs;
    unsigned long t1, t2;

    t1 = GET_TICK_COUNT();  
    MinLs = Minas = Minbs = 1000000.0;
    MaxLs = Maxas = Maxbs = 0.0;

    for (i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<256;j++)
        {
            for (k=0;k<256;k++)
            {
                X = 0.4124*CielabValues[i] + 0.3576*CielabValues[j] + 0.1805*CielabValues[k];
                Y = 0.2126*CielabValues[i] + 0.7152*CielabValues[j] + 0.0722*CielabValues[k];
                Z = 0.0193*CielabValues[i] + 0.1192*CielabValues[j] + 0.9505*CielabValues[k];

                p = X * InvXn;
                q = Y;
                r = Z * InvZn;

                if (q>0.008856)
                {
                    Ls = 116*pow(q,third)-16;
                }
                else
                {
                    Ls = 903.3*q;
                }

                if (q<=0.008856)
                {
                    q1 = 7.787*q+seiz;
                }
                else
                {
                    q1 = pow(q,third);
                }

                if (p<=0.008856)
                {
                    p1 = 7.787*p+seiz;
                }
                else
                {
                    p1 = pow(p,third);
                }

                if (r<=0.008856)
                {
                    r1 = 7.787*r+seiz;
                }
                else
                {
                    r1 = pow(r,third);
                }

                as = 500*(p1-q1);
                bs = 200*(q1-r1);

                //
                // cast on short int for reducing array size
                // 
                FullValuesLs[i][j][k] = (char) (Ls);
                FullValuesas[i][j][k] = (char) (as);
                FullValuesbs[i][j][k] = (char) (bs);

                            //// Remove this and get slower code    
                if (MaxLs<Ls)
                    MaxLs = Ls;
                if ((abs(Ls)<MinLs) && (abs(Ls)>0))
                    MinLs = Ls;

                if (Maxas<as)
                    Maxas = as;
                if ((abs(as)<Minas) && (abs(as)>0))
                    Minas = as;

                if (Maxbs<bs)
                    Maxbs = bs;
                if ((abs(bs)<Minbs) && (abs(bs)>0))
                    Minbs = bs;
                            //// End of Remove

            }
        }
    }

    TRACE(_T("LMax = %f LMin = %f\n"),(MaxLs),(MinLs));
    TRACE(_T("aMax = %f aMin = %f\n"),(Maxas),(Minas));
    TRACE(_T("bMax = %f bMin = %f\n"),(Maxbs),(Minbs));
    t2 = GET_TICK_COUNT();
    TRACE(_T("WhiteBalance init : %lu ms\n"), t2 - t1); 
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime you're talking about? How many samples do you have? Did you try moving the output statements outside the timed section?

Comment: `the execution time is actually longer than with the test`: Care to show  **_what tests_ have been removed?** 'The tests' is not exactly clear (putting it mildly, putting it mildly)

Comment: What are the exact lines you removed ?

Comment: What compiler optimization switches are you using?

Comment: It might be interesting to see what the difference is in the generated assembly is by passing `-S` (and for my poor eyes `-masm=intel` if this is an x86/x64 platform).

Comment: The code executes as expected on my machine, (without proper data of course) faster (0.8s) with the marked section omitted, slower (1.4s) with the marked section included.

Answer (score 2):

I think compiler is trying to unroll the inner loop because you are removing dependency between iterations. But somehow this doesn't help in your case. Maybe because the loop is too big and using too many registers to be unrolled.

Try to turn off unrolling and post results again.

If this is the case, I would suggest you to submit a performance issue to gcc.

PS. I think you can merge `if (q>0.008856)` and `if (q<=0.008856)`.

Comment: disabling unrolling with --params max-unrolled-insns=10 seems to give better results, but it seems my time measurement is not constant across different runs

Comment: It looks like you are using `clock` function: `The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its the cache, maybe unrolling problems, there is only one way to answer this: look at the generated code (e.g. by using the `-S` option). Maybe you can post it/or spot the difference when comparing them.

EDIT: As you now clarified that it was just the measurement I can only recommend (or better command ;-) you, that when you want to get runtime numbers: ALWAYS put it into some loop and average it. Best to do it outside your programm (in a shell script), so your cache is not already filled with the right data.

Comment: Compare what? And how would you detect cache problems just by looking at assm. I think it is better to detect which optimization is breaking the performance by turning them off layer by layer and use oprofile or VTune to localize the issue.

Comment: Compare the output of the assembler code with and without the min/max code. You wont detect cache problems with it - but with 50% difference I would assume that it is more than just cache problems. And there I would expect different code.

Comment: The problem is that larger code could work faster sometimes. But you have a point: if you see that faster code is not unrolled, than try to turn off unrolling.